# Письмо в формате HTML

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте. 
Программа отправляет почту в HTML формате. Точнее, должна это делать. Вот кусочек программы:

```
  $innerstartHT=$objectCGI->start_html(-title=>$titcard,
                                  -base=>'true',
                         -style=>{'src'=>$cssdadr});
  $innerm="<img src=".$cardadr.">\n";
  $innerm.=$gret\n;
  $innerm.=$lnkstr;

  $inner.=$innerstartHT.$innerm.$innerend;
 my $header ="From:<$adrm>\n";
    $header.="To:<$adr>\n";
    $header.="Subject:$titcard\n";
    $header.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $header.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
  open (MAIL,"| /usr/bin/sendmail -t");
print MAIL "$header";
print MAIL "$inner";
close MAIL or die ("Oшибка $!");
```

И письмо отправляется и принимается. Но в текстовом формате. Данные заголовка

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
```

получаются телом письма. И, соответственно, дальше вместо рисунка, текста и пр печатаются их теги.  
 Как правильно "объяснить" почтовой программе формат письма?

**Добавлено.**

```
From:<el-ales@mail.ru>
To:<el-ales@mail.ru>
Subject:С Новым Годом!
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>С Новым Годом!
</title>
<base href="http://dz12.ru/cgi/sendcard.cgi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dz12.ru/css/ne.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
</head>
<body>
здесь нормально отображается рисунок
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Особо не вчитывался, но вижу косяк - `text/html`.

Comment: Скорее всего в этом и вся проблема.

Comment: Спасибо. Это я исправила. Но проблема осталась

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;
my $adr='my@domain.ru';

my $inner='hello <b>world</b>';
my $header ="From:<$adr>\n";
    $header.="To:<$adr>\n";
    $header.="Subject:hello html\n";
    $header.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $header.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
  open (MAIL,"| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
print MAIL "$header";
print MAIL "$inner";
close MAIL or die ("Oшибка $!");

Все прекрасно работает, проверил. Быть может ваш почтовый клиент представляет письмо из html в txt ?

Comment: Ага, а эти модули -
  strict
  warnings
 я их не использовала, может дело в этом?
 И насчет почтового клиента- мне приходят письма в формате HTML, наверное все дело в моем скрипте

Comment: в модулях не должно быть, они исключительно для хорошего кода)
попробуйте строку с open  заменить на open (MAIL,">/tmp/mymail.txt");
и после работы скрипта посмотреть что в этом файле, а еще лучше сюда показать.

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: А из всех возможностей html вы хотите вставить лишь картинку?

Comment: если, вы преверяете по наличию картинки, то быть может стоит посмотреть в эту сторону http://webcorp.ru/page/insert_picture.html как должна быть она представлена в письме

Comment: Нет, не только картинку. Я ее оставила для проверки. Там должна быть ссылка на таблицу стилей, то есть нужны теги <head>, текст, ссылка. Попробую с модулем MIME::Lite

Answer (score 1):

```
use MIME::Lite;
my $mailer = MIME::Lite->new(
    Subject => $subject,
    From    => $from,
    To      => $to,
    Type    => 'text/html',
    Data    => $email,
);
$mailer->send;
```

И всё :)

Comment: Всем, кто уделил внимание этому вопросу -большое спасибо